# differences between using get, or not TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm new in typescript, after reading a code, I found this

1. `get diagnostic(){ return JSON.stringify("test"); }`

after observing in my IDE with this case:

2. `diagnostic(): string { return JSON.stringify("test"); }`
3. `get diagnostic(): string { return JSON.stringify("test"); }`

I wonder if they are exactly the same case 2 and 3, and can be used anywhere in the same or in some cases, is only possible to use the 3, or 1, or 2.

On the other hand, I can understand that the case 1 should not make explicit declaration return type, because it is inferred in return?

sorry for my bad English, and I hope you can understand me what I ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The get keyword is used to create a getter and is actually not exclusive to Typescript, it's an ES5 feature. If you use the get keyword, you'll access it like a property. Otherwise, you access it like a function.

Here's an example of using a getter.

```
class MyClass {
    get thing() {
        return "thing";
    }
}

const foo = new MyClass();
console.log(foo.thing);
```

Same thing without a getter:

```
class MyClass {
    thing() {
        return "thing";
    }
}

const foo = new MyClass();
console.log(foo.thing());
```

Notice that one has parenthesis and the other one doesn't